# Socket tcp connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, try-catch

I'm developing an application on android studio. I'm trying to  open a socket connection.

When the user enters the right IP address, everything works fine, but  if the address is not the right IP, the `Socket` is not connected.

But the problem is that the `Socket` does not throw an catch `Exception`, the app is running and now if the user enters  the right ip address, the socket is not connected.

My question is why it does not throw an catch `Exception` if the IP address is not the right IP and how can I make it work?

Here is the code

```
   try {
        sockettcp = new Socket(Address, Port);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        valid = false;
    }
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't enter the catch block?

Comment: @fildor with Debug mode

Comment: My guess is that your application "Freezes"?

Comment: Ok, does it block on that line (not going any further) or is execution continued beyond that line skipping the catch block?

Comment: @Igoranze Yes excatly

Comment: I suggest you are doing networking on the main thread or the GUI thread. `new Socket(address, port)` can block for up to about a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal way of `Socket` is that it tries to connect to the given IP on the given Port.

If for some reason the IP is not the right one, the `Socket` will not throw an err, instead it will "timeout" trying to reconnect every minute or so (Main thread or the GUI thread).

The 4 errors that are Thrown by this type of constructor `public Socket(String host, int port)` are:

```
IOException //- if an error occurs during the connection

SocketTimeoutException //- if timeout expires before connecting

IllegalBlockingModeException //- if this socket has an associated channel, and the channel is in non-blocking mode

IllegalArgumentException //- if endpoint is null or is a SocketAddress subclass not supported by this socket
```

To "Fix" your problem, you can set the timeout to your value (this cannot exceed the platform default)

```
Socket sck = new Socket();
sck.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), timeout);
```

To "Check" if your `Socket` is connected, you could try this:

```
Socket.isConnected(); //Returns the connection state of the socket.
```

**Note:** Closing a socket doesn't clear its connection state, which means this method will return true for a closed socket (see `isClosed()`) if it was successfully connected prior to being closed.

See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) for more info about the`Socket`.

Comment: @EJP I 'm trying to understind what you mean, but I have a very bad English and I'm not a pro on Network communication. Sorry

Comment: I repeat. 'The `Socket` will not throw an err[or], instead it will "timeout" trying to reconnect every minute or so (Platform default)' is baseless guesswork. If there is an immediate negative response (RST) a `ConnectException: connection refused` is thrown *immediately*. If there is *no* response, the connection is retried at increasing intervals, for a *total* of around a minute, after which a `ConnectException: connect timeout` is thrown. The part about '(Main thread or the GUI thread)' is meaningless in this context and appears to have been just mindlessly copied from another comment.